# Fixed position div inside pos:relative & overflow-y:scroll

Tags: html, css, web

I want to have a div with fixed position inside a div with overflow-y:scroll, meaning I want the div to stay in place while the rest of the content scrolls normally.
And I can't figure out what is wrong, could anyone help? thanks in advance...

```
.foo {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.bar {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar"><div><!-- end of div that should be fixed -->
    <div class="someOther">...</div>
    <div class="someOther">...</div>
    <div class="someOther">...</div>
    <div class="someOther">...</div>
</div><!-- end of container -->
```

Comment: A fixed element's position is relative to the ENTIRE PAGE, not it's parent element.

Answer (score 23):

When you apply `position:fixed` to an element, you are positioning it in relation to the window itself, not its parent element. You'll want to use `position:absolute` to position a child in relation to its parent, as long as the parent has a position other than `position:static`, the default position.

As you correctly did in your example, apply `position:relative` to the parent `.foo` and then apply `position:absolute` to the child `.bar`. Normally, this would achieve the desired result of snapping the `.bar` to the top of the parent, but since there is an overflow of child content in the parent div, and `overflow-y:scroll` scrolls *all* the child content, `.bar` has to scroll as well. See the top example in [my Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/X3SdH/2/).

To fix that, wrap the content you want to scroll in another container with `overflow-y:scroll` on and remove `overflow-y:scroll` on `.foo` to prevent `.bar` from scrolling.

To see the working example that you can adapt, see the bottom example in [my Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/X3SdH/2/).

Comment: How can I make the bar at the top not cover the scrollbar when there is one?

Answer (score 5):

A fixed elements position is relative to the entire document you are viewing, not whatever the parent element is. If you want that to work, you'd need something like this:

CSS

```
.foo {
    height : 300px;
    position : relative;
    width : 100%;
}
.bar {
    border-bottom : 1px solid #000;
    height : 50px;
}
.scollable_content {
    height : 250px;
    overflow-y : auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="scrollable_content">
        <div class="someOther">...</div>
        <div class="someOther">...</div>
        <div class="someOther">...</div>
        <div class="someOther">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4VHx/) for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the thing is that i need to have '.bar' and scrollable_content at the same level/depth (because of a few z-index manipulations).

Comment: You'll have to use Javascript to control it, then. Otherwise, you can manipulate your HTML and CSS to do what you need, which is probably easier.