# Table head fixed with scrolling table - 3 different tables on one page

Tags: html, css-position, css-tables

I've seen many other similar questions but they all concern a single table.

I have a page with 3 different tables on it with similar headings, inside a relative div, with overflow being scrollable.

I split each table into 2 tables - one for the headings and one for the dynamic content, setting the heading table as position:fixed.

When I scroll down inside the div, it works fine, but when I scroll the page down to see the next table, the page scrolls down but the table headings remain fixed in relation to the page.

I want them to move up with their container relative div.

How can I do this?

Comment: I thought I found a solution here : https://www.gravitywell.co.uk/latest/design/posts/css-tip-fixed-positioning-inside-a-relative-container/  but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK... rather simple and the answer came from the first response to the question on [Fixed position div inside pos:relative & overflow-y:scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241068/fixed-position-div-inside-posrelative-overflow-yscroll).

It's a matter of setting the position to absolute.

Thanks all.