# How to place a div at the bottom of another div. Such that when the parent div is scrolled the child div doesn't move

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a messaging app so it's just like whatsapp. I am making a parent div which contains messages. The child div contains the text field and send button. I want to position the child div such that when you scroll through messages the text field and the button remain at the bottom of the parent container.I have already used bootstrap 4's fixed bottom. But It doesn't work...

I have also seen other stack flow answers which say: To put position: relative; in the parent and position: absolute in the child div. But this also doesn't work.

This is my parent container..

```
<div class="container justify-content-center w-50 position-relative" style="height: 400px; overflow-y: auto; ">
<app-message-container></app-message-container>
</div>
```

This is my child container i.e app-message-container..

```
<div class="container d-flex fixed-bottom position-absolute">
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text">
<button class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
</div>
<p>Alias inventore doloremque inceptos soluta, aliqua quaerat totam 
sccusantium quibusdam dolor vestibulum. Class? Non sapiente exercitation 
libero quaerat hic sociis voluptas laboris! Interdum nemo mattis posuere 
fermentum mus auctor iaculis adipisci? Blandit.</p>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please include the code in your question

Comment: Put your code here to get solution/suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Position element at bottom of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621120/position-element-at-bottom-of-div)

Comment: I have updated the question with code.

Comment: You might want to read about CSS regarding `position` - depending on your use-case, you might be interested in either the `absolute` or `fixed` position values.

Comment: After reading only I have used position attribute and their combinations

Comment: You need to put your child container inside the parent and remove the position-absolute from the child and just increase the height of your parent so you can scroll. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQXgzr

Comment: It doesn't do it @JulianEspinosa. If I do that the child container will stick to the bottom of the window not the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to remove `position-absolute` and `position-relative` class if you already use `fixed-bottom` (is `position: fixed` which is correct in your case).

`<div class="container d-flex fixed-bottom">`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container justify-content-center w-50" style="height: 400px; overflow-y: auto; ">  
  <div class="container d-flex fixed-bottom">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text">
     <button class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
  </div>
  <p>Alias inventore doloremque inceptos soluta, aliqua quaerat totam 
  sccusantium quibusdam dolor vestibulum. Class? Non sapiente exercitation 
  libero quaerat hic sociis voluptas laboris! Interdum nemo mattis posuere 
  fermentum mus auctor iaculis adipisci? Blandit.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fixed position div inside pos:relative & overflow-y:scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241068/fixed-position-div-inside-posrelative-overflow-yscroll)

This should help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1489834/jay-bee-why